# How to correctly use allowNull constraint on sequelize belongsToMany associations?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two models, `book` and `author` and I associate them in a many to many relationship with an implicit junction table using `sequelize 6.25.3`. I want the creation of a book to fail if no authors were sent with the POST request.

I followed the [official sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/associations/base.js%7Eassociation) and a lot of Github issues and Stackoverflow questions, and all said to use the `allowNull: false` constraint in a `foreignKey` object.

But somehow that does not work in my case. When I post a book without adding authors to the request, it still succeeds. The Book is saved to the database. It doesn't add data to the junction table, which is correct, but it should not save the Book either.

After the POST request and the INSERT statement, there is a SELECT statement which looks wrong, because it looks for an authorId of null. I added the statement at the bottom of the question.

What am I doing wrong?

If I should post more code, please tell me what code would be relevant.

***Author Model***

```
class Author extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    Author.belongsToMany(models.Book, {
      through: 'BookAuthors',
      foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false,
        name: 'authorId'
      }
    })
  }
};
```

***Book Model***

```
class Book extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    Book.belongsToMany(models.Author, {
      as: 'authors',
      through: 'BookAuthors',
      foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false,
        name: 'bookId'
      }
    })
  }
};
```

***executed SELECT from server console***

```
Executing (default): SELECT "createdAt", "updatedAt", "authorId", "bookId" FROM "BookAuthors" AS "BookAuthors" WHERE "BookAuthors"."bookId" = 6 AND "BookAuthors"."authorId" IN (NULL);
```

Comment: The books and authors themselves are independent and only records in the junction table shows that certain authors linked to certain books. So basically either you have a record with Author 1 and Book 1 in the junction table or not and only that fact indicates that a relationship exists between Author 1 and Book 1. If this record will have one of two foreign keys equal to `null` it does not make sense. You either create a record to link an author and a book or not.

Comment: You‘re right. It doesn‘t make sense. That‘s why I want sequelize to throw an error instead of writing the Book record to the database. Is there another way to achieve this apart from constraining the foreign key? I always thought going through the foreign key would be the right choice. Like a sort of cascade that stops when an association is missing.

Comment: It works only in 1:N relationships when you decide what to do with parent's link in child records when you delete a parent record or create a child record.